# Scaling image dimension

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an image that should cover the dimension of the screen, how can I do?

```
logoPor: {
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        resizeMode: 'cover',
        height:40,
        justifyContent: "center",
    }
```

In this way the image resulting zooming and only a part is showed.

Comment: [background-size: cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: it is not valid in react native :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved using:

```
logoPor: {
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        resizeMode: "stretch",
        justifyContent: "center",
        height: 50,
        width: 350,
        borderWidth: 1
    }
```